# Finding links on YouTube with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm doing web scraping on YouTube with Beautiful Soup.
My goal is to find all the video links from a YouTube search page:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stfu")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
```

I'm searching for this element:

```
<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope 
ytd-video-renderer" title="PINK GUY - STFU" 
href="/watch?v=OLpeX4RRo28" ...
```

I search for all the "a" tag elements but I only get a few:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(a)
```

Resultant links seem to be from the "help" section or something similar, not the body:

```
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Información</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/press/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Prensa</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/copyright/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Derechos de autor</a>
<a href="/t/contact_us" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Contacto</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/creators/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Creadores</a>
```

When I print all the soup object to check the response I noticed that the place where the video info should be seems empty:

```
<div class="video-skeleton">
<div class="video-details">
<div class="thumbnail skeleton-bg-color"></div>
<div class="details flex-1">
<div class="video-title text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>
<div class="video-meta text-shell skeleton-bg-color"></div>
```

This is where my links are supposed to be but nothing inside.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are making a `HTTP` request, while youtube renders the video data using `JavaScript`. To be able to parse to soup the `JS` content, you have to use the library which supports making request and then rendering it with JS.

Comment: @AjapolloTrukatila `requests_html ` module. https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Youtube search results using the youtube api. Examples for many programming languages are available: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples